# PHP: Use floats with given precision in json_encode() function

Tags: php, json, floating-point, precision, encode

I need to use PHP floats in JSON string. Code:

```
$obj['val'] = '6.40';
json_encode($obj);
```

is converted to:

```
{"val": "6.40"}
```

It's OK - I have string value '6.40' in PHP and I have string value "6.40" in JSON.

The situation is not so good if I need to use floats:

```
$obj['val'] = 6.40;
json_encode($obj);
```

is converted to:

```
{"val": 6.4000000000000004}
```

but I need:

```
{"val": 6.40}
```

How can I convert PHP floats to JSON number in 'json_encode' with given precision?

Comment: GOOGLE `what every programmer needs to know about floating point`

Comment: the question is not "how to round floats in PHP?" the question is "how to round floats in 'json_encode' function?"

Comment: Floats are never 100% accurate; you cannot depend on a float have any one specific accurate value. You must live with imprecisions when using floats.

Comment: python converts own floats to JSON numbers with given precision: `round(tools.float_round(6.40, precision_digits=2), 2)`

Comment: yes, PHP floats are not 100% accurate but what about JSON numbers? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp

Comment: there is `ini_set('serialize_precision', ...)` option in PHP that affects to the output of `json_encode()`

Comment: `ini_set('precision', ...)` is the right answer.